# File.Exists -- do NOT want to create new file

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding - so bear with me. I've done a lot of reading and can't figure this one out.

So when you run my new the app, you type in a folder name. The app goes to that folder, then will scan through 2 different log files that are in this designated folder. BUT here is where I'm getting in trouble. If the log does NOT exist - it will ask if you want to create the file that it is looking for... I do NOT want it to do that. I would just like it to go to the folder, if the file does not exist then do nothing and move on to the next line of code.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get node id from user and build path to logs
    string nodeID = txtNodeID.Text;
    string serverPath = @"\\Jhexas02.phiext.com\rwdata\node\";
    string fullPath = serverPath + nodeID;
    string dbtoolPath = fullPath + "\\DBTool_2013.log";
    string msgErrorPath = fullPath + "\\MsgError.log";

    //check if logs exist
    if (File.Exists(dbtoolPath) == true)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", dbtoolPath);
    }
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The 2013 DBTool log does not exist for this Node.");
    }
```

The app will display `The 2013 DBTool log does not exist for this Node.` - then it opens Notepad and asks me if it wants to create the file.

```
Cannot find the \\Jhexas02.phiext.com\rwdata\node\R2379495\DBTool_2013.log file.

Do you want to create a new file?
```

I DO NOT want to create a new file, ever. Any good ways to get around this?

Comment: Based on your code, it does not appear that notepad should be launching if the file does not exist, ut it looks like you haven't given us the complete code.  Is there another start command elsewhere in your app?

Comment: if the file exists, the user should be notified that dbtool log does not exist? why so shady?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code compiles (it's valid to just add bracers like that) it could be as simple as adding `else` to your `if` statement:

```
if (File.Exists(dbtoolPath) == true) // This line could be changed to: if (File.Exists(dbtoolPath))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", dbtoolPath);
}
else // Add this line.
{
    MessageBox.Show("The 2013 DBTool log does not exist for this Node.");
}
```

---

As your code looks now, this part will always run:

```
{
    MessageBox.Show("The 2013 DBTool log does not exist for this Node.");
}
```

It's essentially the same as this code:

```
if (File.Exists(dbtoolPath) == true)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", dbtoolPath);
}

MessageBox.Show("The 2013 DBTool log does not exist for this Node.");
```

Comment: Got it - adding in the ELSE statement worked. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @a8e Great =) Remember to accept an answer you see as the correct one, so it can help future visitors with the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

You skipped "Else" after "if"

```
if (File.Exists(dbtoolPath) == true)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", dbtoolPath);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The 2013 DBTool log does not exist for this Node.");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
if (File.Exists(dbtoolPath))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", dbtoolPath);
    }
else {
        MessageBox.Show("The 2013 DBTool log does not exist for this Node.");
    }
```